# What will be faster - grep or pandas TextFileReader for a very large file?

Tags: python, pandas, grep

I need to search for a particular regex in a very large file I can't load to memory or create dataframe of. Which one, grep or iterating over a TextFileReader will be faster in that case?

Sadly, I don't have time to learn, configure and run a Hadoop.

Cheers

Comment: usually people don't use pandas just for grep'ping text - for that people use `grep` ;) And yes, `grep` will most probably be faster

Comment: `Sadly, I don't have time to learn,` You will. After you failed.

Comment: Using Hadoop (it's distributed file system) would be a good and fast option if you can afford it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since grep is a compiled C program grep is certainly faster than interpreting bytecode for file scan AND regex processing (although regex lib is native code)

Running with pypy could close the gap, but in the end the compiled code would win.

Of course, on smaller data, if data could be stored in a dictionary, multiple search operations would be faster than calling grep the same number of time because grep search is `O(n)` and dictionary search is `O(log(N))`